# Change numbering of captions in figures

Tags: floats, numbering, captions

Does anyone know how I can change the way that the figures get numbering in the caption?  That is because I just see something like **Figure 4-1.:** and I just want **Figure 4.1:**. I used `\package{caption}` and I thought I would solve the problem, but it is not as I did.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Kap4/BPM1.jpeg}
\caption{Description} 
\label{fig:Bpm1}
\end{figure}
```

and it results in...

[image]

---

My document's preamble is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,spanish,fleqn,openany,letterpaper,pagesize]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{eepic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating} 

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter-\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\textbf{\thechapter-\arabic{figure}}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\textbf{\thechapter-\arabic{table}}}


\pagestyle{fancyplain}%\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
\textheight22.5cm \topmargin0cm \textwidth16.5cm
\oddsidemargin0.5cm \evensidemargin-0.5cm%
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\; #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\; #1}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}
\fancyfoot{}
\thispagestyle{fancy}%


\addtolength{\headwidth}{0cm}
\unitlength1mm %Define la unidad LE para Figuras
\mathindent0cm %Define la distancia de las formulas al texto,  fleqn las descentra
\marginparwidth0cm
\parindent0cm %Define la distancia de la primera linea de un parrafo a la margen

%Para tablas,  redefine el backschlash en tablas donde se define la posici\'{o}n del texto en las
%casillas (con \centering \raggedright o \raggedleft)
\newcommand{\PreserveBackslash}[1]{\let\temp=\\#1\let\\=\temp}
\let\PBS=\PreserveBackslash

%Espacio entre lineas
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}

%Neuer Befehl f\"{u}r die Tabelle Eigenschaften der Aktivkohlen
\newcommand{\arr}[1]{\raisebox{1.5ex}[0cm][0cm]{#1}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This can be done with the `caption` package, but it depends on your document class and possibly on loaded packages. Could you post a small compilable code?

Comment: Just looking at your code below, I see that you redefine `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\textbf{\thechapter-\arabic{figure}}}`. Drop this or do something with a period instead of the hyphen.

Comment: Thank you @marmot. 
The problem was partially solved, I  change the hyphen for just the point, but I can still see at the end of listing the figure ".:", That is, " Figure 4.1 .: ".

Comment: @FermínPérezSuárez Using the option `labelformat=simple` when loading the caption package should drop the extra period. (See also: KOMA-Script documentation, keyword "autodot")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the following three lines of code in the document's preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter-\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\textbf{\thechapter-\arabic{figure}}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\textbf{\thechapter-\arabic{table}}}
```

I leave it to your imagination to guess what the `-` character between `\thechapter` and `\arabic{...}` does.

A separate comment: Some of the packages that are being loaded in the preamble are either badly deprecated or have been superseded by other, more capable packages. (Did you copy your preamble from somebody?) For instance, don't load the `subfigure` package; in its place, load either the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package. There should be no need to load the `epsfig` package, especially as the `graphicx` package is being loaded anyway. Do you really need to load both the `lscape` and the `rotating` packages?

Comment: Hi, @Micco, thanks for the answer, I solve the problem. The file in fact is a template.  I use your recommendations. Thanks you