# Issue with Referencing Figures from Supplementary Information in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, cross-referencing

I am working on a LaTeX document where I have a main document and supplementary information (SI). In the SI, I want to maintain the sequence "Figure S1, Figure S2..." for labeling the figures. In the main document, I want to reference these figures from the SI using the \ref{} command, but I'm encountering some issues.

Here's a simplified version of my setup:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Main Document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Example A}
    \label{fig:example_a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Example B}
    \label{fig:example_b}
\end{figure}

Text in the main document attempting to call the figures from the Supplementary Information: Figure \ref{fig:example_c} and Figure \ref{fig:example_d}.


\end{document}
```

support_information.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Supplementary Information}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Example C}
    \label{fig:example_c}
\end{figure}
```

\end{document}

It is crucial that the sequence in both documents be distinct: 'Figure 1', 'Figure 2',... for the main document and 'Figure S1', 'Figure S2',... for the Supplementary Information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two answers that could help

1. Change the figure captions

[Change numbering of captions in figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429967/change-numbering-of-captions-in-figures)

2. Use references from other documents

[Cross-referencing between different files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14364/cross-referencing-between-different-files)

Comment: Example in https://www.overleaf.com/read/bnrdvvhrmvdq#4d4e18

Answer (score 1):

This uses `\include` and `\includeonly` to combine both files, but only print one at a time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\includeonly{test5,test6}% print both

\begin{document}
\include{test6}% main text

\setcounter{page}{1}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{S\arabic{page}}

\include{test5}% supplemental
\end{document}
```

Stored as test6.tex:

```
\section{Main Document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Example A}
    \label{fig:example_a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Example B}
    \label{fig:example_b}
\end{figure}

Text in the main document attempting to call the figures from the Supplementary Information: Figure \ref{fig:example_c}.
```

Stored as test5.tex

```
\section{Supplementary Information}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Example C}
    \label{fig:example_c}
\end{figure}
```