What is the best way to organize a thesis into two or more volumes?
My PhD thesis will be composed of at least two volumes when printed: a first volume of synthesis, and a second volume of annexes and the like. I would like to be able to cross-reference between the two volumes.
What is the best way to do this with XeLaTeX?
I thought of resetting the page numbers at every "part", and using some other software to simply split the PDF in two afterwards, but perhaps there is a more elegant way to do this?

Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/712888/issue-with-referencing-figures-from-supplementary-information-in-latex

There is a way that I have used to reference a separate LaTeX document with supplementary material from a "main" document (the publication file) using the package xr (https://ctan.joethei.xyz/macros/latex/required/tools/xr.pdf), written by one of the very active members of this forum.
Putting \externaldocument{second_volume} into the preamble of the first document allows you to reference labels in second_volume.tex.
